# Why are my wirelessly sent data getting corrupted?

Tags: arduino-uno, corruption, wireless

I am making a project using the CC1101 wireless module and the [RadioLib](https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib) library.

I have been trying the [CC1101_Receive_Address](https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib/blob/master/examples/CC1101/CC1101_Receive_Address/CC1101_Receive_Address.ino) and [CC1101_Transmit_Address](https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib/blob/master/examples/CC1101/CC1101_Transmit_Address/CC1101_Transmit_Address.ino) examples from the library

I noticed that the last symbol in the `"Hello world!"` message was getting corrupted - it was always replaced with something random, such as `>$, "@` or something similar. I also tried sending a readout from a BMI sensor, but the other side did not receive it at all and only showed the random symbols. I tried sending the readouts as an int, float and byte variables, but it did not help. What could be causing this? Is it more likely a software or a hardware problem?

The problems occurred when using Arduino Uno R3 on the transmitting side and Uno R4 WIFI on the receiving end, with pinouts the same on both sides:

```
Vcc - 3.3V
GND - gnd
MOSI - D11
SClk - D13
MISO - D12
GDO2 - D2
GDO0 (optional, but connected) - D3
CSN - D10
```

I am using [this specific variant](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006440698413.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.47.72497ff7czTHpM&algo_pvid=5d370251-5dea-4290-bf35-31c045851554&algo_exp_id=5d370251-5dea-4290-bf35-31c045851554-23&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21CZK%21257.39%2111.73%21%21%2178.03%213.55%21%40211b612817115494208761030ec04b%2112000037175069114%21sea%21CZ%210%21AB&curPageLogUid=jRATp7SUW13F&utparam-url=scene%3Asearch%7Cquery_from%3A) of the CC1101.

If you need any more information, I'll do my best to provide it.

When trying to solve this problem I tried changing the sent data to a variable, but that did not get sent at all. I also plan to try and replace the modules, but I currently have no spares.